# Proof : Every bijective function $f: A \rightarrow \mathcal R$ is order preserving.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, discrete-mathematics

We know that ($\mathcal R, \geq)$ is a poset. Let $A, B \in \mathcal R$. Then, a function $f: A \rightarrow B$ is said to be *order-preserving* iff $\forall x, y \in A, x \geq y$ iff $f(x) \geq f(y)$. Every bijective function $f: A \rightarrow \mathcal R$ is order preserving.

Attempt:

Since $f$ is bijective, $\exists x \in A \forall f(x) \in B$. Suppose $f(x) \not \geq f(y)$ and $x=y$. However, $x=y$ implies that $f(x)=f(y)$ due to injectiviness of $f$, a contradiction. Therefore $f(x) \geq f(y)$.

Furthermore, suppose that $f(x) \geq f(y)$, particularly $f(x) = f(y)$ and $x \not = y$, w.l.o.g. $y=x$.

But I am stuck here, my arguments are not convincing to me, something feels off. I am able to show that if $x=y$ then $f(x) = f(y)$ but this to me does not transalte to $x\geq y$ and $f(x) \geq f(y)$. How can I establish this fact by using the bijectiviness of $f$?

Comment: Consider the counterexample $f(x)=-x$.

Comment: $x=y$ implies that $f(x)=f(y)$ due to $f$ being a function.  This has nothing to do with injectivity.  It is the converse statement of that which would be about injectivity, that $f(x)=f(y)$ could imply $x=y$ if we knew $f$ was injective.

Comment: Then my intuition that something is off is correct, this only works if we restrict $f$ to be increasing or decreasing, right? A counter example suggests that this statement is wrong.

Comment: What we can say : If $f(x)$ is continous in some interval $[a,b]$ , it is bijective there if and only if it is either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing. If the function need not be continous , we can find arbitary pathological functions which are still bijective without having useful monotony properties.